# How do I load extension when viewing local file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using the example taken from [viewer-javascsript-offline.sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample)

I have an extension that was created using nodejs tutorial ([link](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/selection)) that I got it working using the tutorial code to register the extension. However, when I tried the same thing using the offline viewer code sample (using viewer3D instead of viewingApplication), I am not able to view the extension's button.

note: I can guarantee that the handleselectionextension.js is working fine as I've got it working in the tutorial version.

codes:
`index.css` and `index.html`

```css
.handleSelectionToolbarButton {
  background-image: url(https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/raw/master/white/png/24/object-group.png);
  background-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Very Basic 3D Viewer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=4.2.*" type="text/css">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>

  <!-- The Viewer JS -->
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js?v=4.2.*"></script>
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=4.2.*"></script>
  <script src="handleselectionextension.js"></script>

  <!-- Developer JS -->
  <script>
    var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
    var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
    var options = {
      'env': 'Local',
      'document': "0/1/Design.svf",
      'extensions': ["HandleSelectionExtension"]
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
      viewer.start(options.document, options);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension config is not for `Initializer`, you have to pass it to 2nd argument of the viewer constructor like this:

```
var config3d = {
    'extensions': ["HandleSelectionExtension"]
};

var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv, config3d);

var options = {
  'env': 'Local',
  'document': "0/1/Design.svf"
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
  viewer.start(options.document, options);
});
```

Comment: That does fix my problem (although I found another solution which is `viewer.loadExtension(extensionName)`)

Comment: would be nice if the API documentation actually explains what can be provided for the initial config object for `new Viewer3D(container,config)`

Comment: The extension  names in `config3d` will be loaded via `Viewer3D#loadExtension()` while calling `Viewer3D#start()` automatically. It is mentioned in step3 of this official tutorial: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/tutorials/extensions/ :)

Comment: I see. Tutorial shows the usage for the method `ViewingApplication.registerApp(viewableType, viewerClass, config)`,the API [page](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/viewingapplication/) however does not have documentation of what should be provided for `viewerClass` and `config`.   
   
Would be nice if the autodesk team can flesh out their API documentation before creating any more new tutorials.